# jQuery keyup should should trigger enter key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple problem (hopefully), but I am unable to find a clear solution.

I have a datatable, which has a text input field.  The user enters text into the text field, and hits the enter key.  This automatically filters from the text entered.

I was hoping to use the onkeyup event to trigger so when a user enters a value in the text field, the datatable automatically updates, rather than the user having to press enter.

```
<input type="text" name="input" class="filter" id="input" onkeyup="functionName(this)" value="">

<script>
function functionName(e) {
alert(e.value);
}
</script>
```

This code works, so when I enter a value, it pops an alert up displaying the entered value.

Is it possible i can change the alert, to do a submit, or replicate what the "enter" key does.

From trying to find a solution, it is more difficult because it is not a form, as it uses ajax so the .submit methods will not work.

I was also hoping a solution like this could work

```
<script>

var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
e.which = 13; // Enter
$("#input").trigger(e);

</script>
```

I know there are many similar topics, and I have looked, but none of them seem to be the right solution for me.
Thanks for the help.

//

Edit

//

Based on the keyup issue, how can I refocus cursor after filtering. Is this done at the same time as filtering?

```
        $obj.find('input.filter').on('keyup',function(e){
               e.preventDefault();
               ajax($obj);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery, so there's no real need to use `onclick=""`, Secondly try to avoid to use reserved names for IDs & Classes (e.g. `#input`). Lastly, you can *mimic* the form submission by using [`$.post()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) on each `.keyup` event like below:

```
<input type="text" name="input" class="filter" id="searchinput" value="" />

<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $(document).on('keyup', '.filter', function( event ) {
           $.post( 'yourapi.php', { input: $(this).val() }, function( data ) {
               //Refocus the <input />
               $('#searchinput').focus();
           });

       });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm I don't doubt this works, but it isn't for me.  Perhaps the yourapi.php is the reason.  I was so close with the onclick way, do you know a solution using that?

Comment: @user2661760 `yourapi.php` is just an example URL, is the Database Script on the same page as the `input`?

Comment: Yea i guessed that, but nothing happens when I link it correctly.  If i don't link it correctly i get an error in the console.  Nothing is happening on keyup, but still when i hit return it works :/

Comment: No error, no log in the console, thats the problem :D

Comment: Thing is, the 'enter' is probably just the form being submitted to the 'action' attribute within your form, if none stated - I believe it's submitting to *itself*.

Comment: If you check this link out, http://dudapiotr.eu/table/column-filtering
It is an example of what I am trying to edit.  I can't imagine you have used this before, but if you type in the input field and press enter, it filters.  I am trying to make it so it filters upon the keyup (without pressing enter)

Comment: Well, if you look at the source code, it follows the same flow as my answer, upon keydown, use ajax. I think you need to sort out what Ajax issues, because if you check the network tab, is there HTTP Requests being sent out?

Comment: hehe i got it working :D the only problem is on the new loadup the cursor leaves the text input box :p

Comment: @user2661760 Edited the answer for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$("input").keyup(function(event)
{
 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode != '13')
{   
 var e = jQuery.Event("keyup");
 e.which = 13; // Enter
 $("input").trigger(e);

}
  else {alert("Enter triggered");
       }
});
});
```

**DEMO**    [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKgK4/)

Comment: Is this not checking if the enter key is pressed? I do not need that.

Comment: The other problem as i stated it isnt a form, it is a datatable so no <form> tags to submit

Comment: Hey check my new answer i think this is what you want.

Comment: This pretty much what I have, but nothing happens when i type, however when pressing the Enter key, it works as normal.

Comment: @user2661760 The Enter key event is triggering and alert is displayed. It may be some problem with you form not submitting.

Answer (score 0):

As you can code in jquery too. Then you can go with this code......

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".filter").keyup(function(){
                var text_input_text = $(this).val();
                //here is your ajax post request
                 $.post('url for post', {filter_text: text_input_text}, function(response){
                       console.log(response);
                 });
        });
});
```

Here we have covered the keyup event and ajax post.
Hope this will help you.